# Is __declspec(dllexport) of ::vector<std::unique_ptr<user-defined type>> possible?

Tags: c++, stl, unique-ptr, dllexport

I am trying to export a class with a private member `std::vector<std::unique_ptr>`. The dll client should use `Number` objects, so I instantiated it. But now I run into a compiler error:

```
error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Number,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Number
1>          ]
```

Here is my test code

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Number
{
public:
    int i;
};

template class __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Number>>; // to avoid warning C4251

class __declspec(dllexport) A
{
public:
    A(){}
    ~A(){}
    A(A&&) {}
    A& operator=(A&&) { return *this; }

    Number& getNumber(int i) { return *v[i]; }
private:
    A(const A&);
    A& operator=(const A&);

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Number>> v;
};
```

Comment: UDP = ... Uridine Triphosphate? User Datagram Protocol? What?

Comment: Anyway you need to be really careful about allocating memory in one DLL and deallocating in main program or other DLL (i.e. other module).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf why would that be a problem?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: A Windows DLL can use any runtime library internally. It's more like a program than a library. When the runtime library is not the same, and the exported object does not encapsulate and ensure use of original allocator for deallocation, the behavior is very undefined. I use that term loosely because the C++ standard does not support DLLs: it's outside the regime of the standard.

Comment: UDP = user-defined type. I updated the title

Comment: @cheer why would the dll and the program link against different runtime libs though? Should you mot ensure they dont?

Comment: @alex555: thanks, but what does the "P" stand for?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Ideally the programmer would ensure a common runtime lib, by linking with a runtime lib that itself is in a DLL. Linking the runtime statically ensures different runtime libs (that is, at least separate instances of the same lib, with separate states for the their allocators). The ideal is part of the "be really careful". An alternative is to design things to guarantee that the same allocator is used for deallocation as for allocation. On way is to use the same OS-provided instead of C++ allocator everywhere, another way is to pass around a ref to the allocator.